# How to prevent refreshing of webview in navigation drawer

Tags: android, android-fragments, webview

From a while i had been using `viewpager` to display `webview` pages in activity, but now i have change from `viewpager` to `navigation drawer with RecyclerView`, to display `webview`, i have multiple `webview` loading in my activity.

Suppose activity starts on **webview 1** and then i click on **webview 2** if i go back to `webview 1` it will be reloading(refresh) and i want to prevent that from happening.

Please help.

Here is my main activity.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements FragmentDrawer.FragmentDrawerListener {
private Toolbar toolbar;
private FragmentDrawer drawerFragment;

private static String TAG = MainActivity.class.getSimpleName();

@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.ICE_CREAM_SANDWICH)
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.tool_bar);
    if (toolbar != null) {
        toolbar.setTitle(R.string.app_name);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    }
    drawerFragment = (FragmentDrawer)
            getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.fragment_navigation_drawer);
    drawerFragment.setUp(R.id.fragment_navigation_drawer, (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout), toolbar);
    drawerFragment.setDrawerListener(this);


    displayView(0);

    }

@Override
public void onDrawerItemSelected(View view, int position) {
    displayView(position);
}

private void displayView(int position) {
    Fragment fragment = null;
    String title = getString(R.string.app_name);
    switch (position) {
        case 0:
            fragment = new TopRatedFragment();
            title = getString(R.string.title_home);
            break;
        case 1:
            fragment = new GamesFragment();
            title = getString(R.string.title_friends);
            break;
        case 2:
            fragment = new MoviesFragment();
            title = getString(R.string.title_messages);

        default:
            break;
    }

    if (fragment != null) {
        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
        fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.container_body, fragment);
        fragmentTransaction.commit();


        getSupportActionBar().setTitle(title);
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you saying that you want to restore the same fragment? This is from [developer.android.com](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/fragment-ui.html)

```
FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();

// Replace whatever is in the fragment_container view with this fragment,
// and add the transaction to the back stack so the user can navigate back
transaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, newFragment);
transaction.addToBackStack(null);

// Commit the transaction
transaction.commit();
```

This enables the back navigation button to restore the same fragment that already loaded the webview. You are creating a new one each time in the switch statement.

Once you get the back button working how you want it you can easily learn how to manually pull the specific fragment off of the stack.

Edit:

I do not think you are refreshing the webview. You are creating a new fragment each time you select an item by calling the empty constructor. You need to only create each fragment one time and then use the same instance of that fragment when you go back to that webview. Using the back stack will enable it to stay loaded while you leave the application and come back to it later.

Also try using the static method `YourFragment.newInstance(params)` which returns a new instance of YourFragment. Do this instead of the empty constructor, as that is considered incorrect practice.

Comment: I don't think that, this is the correct apporach to do it.

Comment: I have updated my answer with more relevant information. Hopefully this will help you fix your problem.