# How to avoid refresh in a webview app with navigation drawer?

Tags: android, webview

So, the thing is that, if I am in a webview on the app and then tap another option of the menu (also in webview) and then go back to the first option this one will refresh the content, I want to avoid that, because if a put a login screen and the user taps another option and goes back they will have the login screen again even if they are already logged.
I already tried this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37509853/how-to-prevent-refreshing-of-webview-in-navigation-drawer) but didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect the problem is that the WebView is not wired into the lifecycle of your activity/fragment and can not distinguish between the first time it is loaded and subsequent times it is loaded.  Additionally if the WebView is destroyed (highly probable) the WebView must reload the data.

1. Ensure that you are saving and restoring the state of your Activity/Fragment correctly and keep track of which webviews are loaded (you can use a HashMap, or boolean or whatever you like).  https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/activity-lifecycle.html#saras
2. When you go to load your webviews consult the data from step 1 to determine if you need to reload the content.  You may need to pass some data to the HTML to indicate the state (first load etc).